# Hard drive failure with notification to install matrix console

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virus, hard-drive-failure

My wife's computer has suddenly popped up with a notification saying her hard may fail soon. Shortly after a program called Intel matrix storage console asked permission to download. My question is; is this some sort of elaborate virus. Only reason i ask is the attempt of a program we did not download to install itself.

Answer (score -1):

Also check the condition of the drive using any free HDD utility, such as Crystal Disk Info from http://crystalmark.info/ [you might avoid the files with OpenCandy ads]. These utilities use the S.M.A.R.T. info on newer HDD; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring%2C_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology for more info.